# Is it possible to accommodate a scroll view and a ListView in one activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating an app that will support Android 2.2 and above.

In that I have 10 edit texts and 10 text views that I accommodate in a scroll view.

And I wanted to Accommodate a list view also inside the same activity.

Is it possible to accommodate the whole in a single activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a ListView in a ScrollView, but that is a bad design. Even Eclipse will throw a warning. Moreover the behavior will be different, because ListView already has its own ScrollView.

So the only solution could be to have a Fixed length ScrollView and a ListView in some other Layout(Linear/Relative).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible however it's not recommended enclose a list view inside a scroll view since list view has already implemented scrolling and as android documentation says it won't work. What you could do is to create a fragments, and in one fragment place a views that you want to have inside a scroll view and on other fragment - your list view. Then put two fragments inside an activity.

Comment: They are. Use the Support Library v4 http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html

Comment: Thanks for providing me the link..I didn't tried to implement fragment is there any sample source code available for that so that i can learn using that and implement..If you know any link please provide me!!..

Comment: Check this simple tutorial http://neilgoodman.net/2012/01/29/working-with-fragments-on-android-part-1/ It explains the basics of the fragments and how to use them